# Does anyone have extra «» generated from lh-brackets

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Can't seem to find any reason for this, but I have been using Ycm, syntastic, and all the lh- plugins with vim for a while now. In the case of lh-brackets, I used to have a problem with it generating "«»" every time it 'automatically' generated the other bracket, paren, quote, etc.  But it was only happening in .vim files, so i turned it off for vim files in my vimrc. Now nothing has changed, no new scripts installed, and all of the sudden, this happens with ALL files (cpp, h, pl, py, etc). Like i said, not using heavy customization, and everything is default except the disabling of lh-brackets when editing vim files, but that has now become a hotkey since i cant use it anywhere.

**My Question is this: does anyone have this or similar problem with lh-brackets, and if so, any idea how to fix it, or is there some setting I am missing?**

My first thoughts are to go though and check any updated vim scripts (this just happened a day ago) that could have been updated when doing an apt-get upgrade (like debian.vim) but after that I've got nothing...

Answer (score 1):

The placeholders characters can be jumped to (`:h <Plug>MarkersJumpF` -> `<C-J>` with vim, `<m-ins>` with gvim). That's their purpose.

If you have installed lh-cpp, see `:h lh-cpp-first-steps`, you'll find a quick guide to my C++ suite (and lh-brackets incidentally).

EDIT: The plugin was badly designed. I've patched the plugin to rely on `g:usemarks` in order to fix the ergonomic of plugin .
In the (now-) past, if you wanted to set b:usemarks to 0, you'd have needed to add an autocommand that'd set b:usemarks to 0 in all new buffers.

[Now](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/issues), (lh-brackets v2.2.0), if you want to always disable the placeholders/marker characters, you need to set `g:usemarks` to 0, not `b:usemarks`. Buffer-local variables are meant to be set from ftplugins, or tree/project-local plugins which are supported thanks to plugins like [local_vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc).

And as romainl has pointed out, don't hesitate to use the [bug trackers](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/issues), or even to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

hmm found it:

`:let b:usemarks=0`

now needs to be set, apparently that was a marker for integration to another plugin, though i dont use it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not an issue tracker, [this](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/issues/list) is an issue tracker.

Comment: Indeed. The issue tracker would have been a better place. The bug is now fixed, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25035683/15934).